# whois and other tools don't work with IDNs

Tags: command-line, networking, dns, whois

Whois and other tools don't work with international domain names. The names aren't correctly converted to puny code.

```
$ whois ąćęłńóśźż.pl 
Incorrect domain name: ąćęłńóśźż.pl

$ dig ąćęłńóśźż.pl 
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.1-Ubuntu <<>> ąćęłńóśźż.pl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 27368
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;\196\133\196\135\196\153\197\130\197\132\195\179\197\155\197\186\197\188.pl. IN    A
;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 05 20:02:11 CEST 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 50

$ host ąćęłńóśźż.pl 
Host ąćęłńóśźż.pl not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

$ nslookup ąćęłńóśźż.pl 
Server:     127.0.0.53
Address:    127.0.0.53#53
** server can't find \196\133\196\135\196\153\197\130\197\132\195\179\197\155\197\186\197\188.pl: NXDOMAIN
```

I'm pretty sure these tools used to work correctly once upon a time. Has the handling of IDNs changed?

What can be the cause and how do I fix it? Is it a locale issue?

Comment: Have you tried with another DNS server (to eliminate a broken upstream DNS resolver)? `dig @8.8.8.8 ...` should work.

Answer (score 1):

`whois` works for me on 16.04:

```
$ whois ąćęłńóśźż.pl

DOMAIN NAME:           xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl
registrant type:       individual
nameservers:           ns1.dnsprotect.eu.
                       ns2.dnsprotect.eu.
created:               2010.04.15 12:43:23
last modified:         2018.04.10 07:16:15
renewal date:          2019.04.15 12:43:23

no option

dnssec:                Unsigned


REGISTRAR:
Consulting Service Sp. z o.o.
ul. Domaniewska 35A lok.1B
02-672 Warszawa
Polska/Poland
+48.221238080
domeny@ConsultingService.pl

WHOIS database responses: http://www.dns.pl/english/opiskomunikatow_en.html

WHOIS displays data with a delay not exceeding 15 minutes in relation to the .pl Registry system
Registrant data available at http://dns.pl/cgi-bin/en_whois.pl
$
```

As for the other three commands, as a workaround, you could do `sudo apt-get install idn` and then use it to do the translation:

```
$ dig $(idn ąćęłńóśźż.pl)

; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 11814
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl.     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl. 14400 IN     A       46.29.20.209

;; Query time: 273 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Aug 05 20:02:51 EDT 2018
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 70

$ host $(idn ąćęłńóśźż.pl)
xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl has address 46.29.20.209
xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl mail is handled by 10 mail.xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl.
$ nslookup $(idn ąćęłńóśźż.pl)
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   xn--kda9ag6e8jma6nxjsa.pl
Address: 46.29.20.209

$
```